# c# asp.net System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I've a problem. I was sending newsletters to my users, I've more of 10000 email addresses. When i tried to send it with only 6/7 email it worked, now it doesn't work anymore. Why?
I receive this error:

Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1  Too many bad domains

```
[SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1 <rsv1979@yahoo.com> Too many bad domains]

[SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to a recipient.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1648
   Admin_InviaNewsLetter.SendEmailButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +3013
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

I can't understand why! If u need the code, here it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 501; i++)
    {
        destinatario = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][0])));
        msg.To.Add(destinatario);
    }
    string body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(BodyMessageTextBox.Text);
    msg.From = new MailAddress("email@address.it");
    msg.Subject = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ObjectTextBox.Text);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = pzzsopra + body + pzzsotto;
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.sitedomain.it");
    sc.Port = 25;
    sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@address.it", "");
    sc.EnableSsl = false;
    sc.Send(msg);
```

I hope to find the solution. Thank you before!

Comment: "When i tried to send it with only 6/7 email it worked, now it doesn't work anymore." --->> "The server response was: 5.1.1 <rsv1979@yahoo.com> Too many bad domains]" - BAD SPAM! BAD!

Comment: Is the address in specific the problem? I can solve it or I have to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem with that email address, in which case your loop logic needs to handle such errors, forget that one and proceed onwards. However it might be that *your* domain is blacklisted by the recipient mail server (or their infrastructure).

Try this for starters - http://www.aweber.com/blog/email-deliverability/whitelisting-feedback-loops.htm

In my experience, it's better to use a trusted 3rd party to send bulk emails. Try mailchimp or google for 'email campaign software' / 'email newsletter software' - there are lots of providers, most of which have API's your ASP.NET site can talk to.